# Oracle Syncing two databases in different servers

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Need guidance. I have two databases A & B, each residing in different servers. Database A is primary, at the main site and database B is at remote location, user side. Table structure in B is a subset of A. Database B will fetch certain data from A for certain functionalities to work and when data is updated by users in B, they need to be updated in A. The problem here is, the there is connectivity issue between A and B as B is in a remote area.

When connection is alive, both databases should be in sync. And when connection goes off, B should be able to function actions basing on last pulled data from A. and when connection restores, data sync should happen.

I am using Oracle 12c. Please help guys.

Regards

Comment: Is data being modified on both A and B?  So someone could update a particular row on A and someone else could make an incompatible update on B while the link was down?  When you say that "table structure in B is a subset of A" do you mean that B has fewer tables than A?  Or that B has the same tables but a subset of columns?  Or a subset of rows?  Or all three?  Any replication technology will have an ability to queue up changes but that can get rather painful depending on how long the connectivity is down.  If you regularly expect the remote site to go down for several days, for example.

Comment: Hi Justin, Data gets updated on both A & B, the frequency of updation is less though. regarding subset, the number of tables in B is subset of number of tables in A, columns are all same.  I came across Updatable Materialized Views. Can you suggest as to how to go ahead